# Update query on specific columns dynamically with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

Researches on Google, SO or the doc didn't help me.
I have a class with some fields, let's take for example : Person.class

Fields :

```
int ID;
String Name;
Date dateOfBirth;
int sizeInCm; // 178 for example
```

I want to update only one field dynamically in SQL Server without using CriteriaUpdate (too old Hibernate version) nor @DynamicUpdate (I need to update all fields in others methods in my back-end) on the class.

For example the user changes in the view his dateOfBirth and I want only want to persist that.
BUT, I don't know in my method which field will be updated so I need to handle it dynamically.
Should I use Criteria interface (Restrictions) mixed with Native HQL or something ?

Comment: How can you decide which field to update ?

Comment: I have 3 inputs in my method: the ID, the key (String type) and the new value (Object because type is unknown - so cast needed)

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is. Do you want bulk update (CriteriaUpdate) or single entity update? Secondly: @DynamicUpdate changes the way sql is generated so that only modified fields are included in the sql (which has pros and cons). If you modify all fields in other methods, all fields will be included. Thirdly: are you aware of dirty checking?

Comment: I only want to modify the database object whatever the entity is in the persistance context or not so I think bulk update. And for DynamicUpdate, I want in others methods to erase other user modifications on the entity so I need to persist all fields even with some are unchanged. No I don't know dirty checking I will check that.